# trying to display old and new values of a cell in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to display old and new values of a cell before and after saving  in excel using vba i have tried the below code but it is showing some type mismatch error in second last line. I know there is a silly mistake but i am not able to figure that out

```
Dim OldVals As New Dictionary
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        If OldVals.Exists(cell.Address) Then
            Debug.Print "New value of " & cell.Address & " is " & cell.Value & "; old value was " & OldVals(cell.Address)
        Else
            Debug.Print "No old value for " + cell.Address
        End If
        OldVals(cell.Address) = cell.Value
    Next
End Sub

Sub test()

 Worksheet_Change True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten a bit the code and it works quite ok:

```
Option Explicit

Dim OldVals As New Dictionary

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In Target
        If OldVals.Exists(myCell.Address) Then
            Debug.Print "New value of " & myCell.Address & " is " & myCell.Value & _
                 "; old value was " & OldVals(myCell.Address)
        Else
            Debug.Print "No old value for " + myCell.Address
        End If
        OldVals(myCell.Address) = myCell.Value
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

This is what I get in the immediate window, when I enter some values:

```
No old value for $B$1
New value of $B$1 is 12; old value was 3
No old value for $E$10
New value of $E$10 is 2; old value was 5
```

- I have changed `cell` to `myCell`, as far as it is a word, used by the VBEditor.
- In order to use early binding for `OldVals`, you should add a reference `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`: Extras>Libraries>Check MS Scripting Runtime>OK

[image]

Comment: Hi if you want to remove that $ sign in cell name eg $B$1 you can add " & Replace(Selection.Address, "$", "")  "  in the code line

Comment: @saurabh255 - I like the `$` sign :)